# Javascript: How to get .tgz MIME type from HTML file input?

Tags: javascript

I am able to get most file MIME types by checking the file in a HTML file element, however when choosing a .tgz file I do not get a type.

Here is a jsfiddle showing the file type when a file is selected from the HTML file input: http://jsfiddle.net/chrisabrams/cTJKf/

Comment: What browser are you using? This works for me in FireFox 4.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the spec](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/#dfn-type) it's up to the browser to attempt to determine the content-type and if it fails, it should return an empty string.

> **type**
>
> The ASCII-encoded string in lower case representing the media type of
>   the `Blob`, expressed as an RFC2046 MIME type [[RFC2046](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/#RFC2046)]. On getting,
>   conforming user agents MUST return the MIME type of the `Blob`, if it is
>   known. **If conforming user agents cannot determine the media type of
>   the `Blob`, they MUST return the empty string.** A string is a valid MIME
>   type if it matches the `media-type` token defined in section 3.7 "Media
>   Types" of RFC 2616 [[HTTP](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/#HTTP)].

So whatever browser you're using doesn't recognise what a **.tgz** file is - this could vary both per-browser and also per-operating-system however.

I'm using Opera on Linux and it recognises **.tgz** but - for example - doesn't recognise **.xcf**

Comment: Yep - it just returns an empty string for me when the type cannot be detected.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably browser-dependent. It works for me in Opera, and gives `application/x-gzip`, but gives nothing in anything else. You could check it manually with `e.target.files[0].value`.